# Using backbone.js' text.js plugin cannot access template

Tags: templates, backbone.js, requirejs

I get the error GET localhost:8080/scripts/templates/home/homeTemplate.html 404 (Not Found)

Not sure why this is happening.  Based on this tutorial I feel like files are in the right place.  http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/

The github repository is here https://github.com/natecraft1/backbone-widget

I reference the template like this
    'text!templates/home/homeTemplate.html'
from app/templates/home...

Comment: The body of the question as posted on Stack Overflow should contain the data relevant to the problem at hand. Links to external sites are fine, so long as they do not *replace* the contents that should be in the question. Here you should at least have your RequireJS config and show the code in which you use your template. (Careful abbreviation is fine if the code is long.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `scripts/main.js` as follows.

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone',
    templates: '../templates'  // added
  }
});
require(['app'], function(App) {
  App.initialize();
});
```

By setting the `templates` as above,
if the module ID starts with "templates",
requirejs load the module from the `templates` directory

Without the above `templates` setting, requirejs load any module IDs from `scripts` directory, which contains `main.js` source code. Thus the `text!templates/home/homeTemplate.html` is interpreted as wrong URL `scripts/templates/home/home/homeTemplate.html`.

If you do not want to modify the `main.js` script,
you can specify the correct location of `homeTemplate.html` by 
replacing the `'text!templates/...'` with

- `'text!../../../templates/home/homeTemplate.html'` or
- `'text!/../templates/home/homeTemplate.html'`